# logstash pattern NOT MATCHED

Tags: logstash, grok

I'm new in **ELK and also Logstash domain**(grok regexp) and I'm facing with **[0] "_grokparsefailure"** on the logstash debugger but I cannot tell what is wrong with my pattern when trying to filter the line below :

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-11-21T08:22:11.288+00:00"},"s":"I", "c":"CONNPOOL", "id":45242, "ctx":"MirrorMaestro","msg":"Connecting","attr":{"hostAndPort":"mongodb-dev:21312"}}
```

**and my pattern used is :**

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{MONGO3_SEVERITY:severity} %{MONGO3_COMPONENT:component}%{SPACE}(?:\[%{DATA:context}\])? %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

**the result of the online grok debugger shows:**

[image]

**Update, meantime I found the solution:**

```
 filter {
        if [type] == "mongo-log" {
            grok {
                match => {"message" => "% 
    {TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\s+%{MONGO3_SEVERITY:severity}\s+% 
    {MONGO3_COMPONENT:component}\s+(?:\[%{DATA:context}\])?\s+% 
    {GREEDYDATA:message}"}
                overwrite => [ "message" ]
                remove_tag => ["beats_input_codec_plain_applied"]
            }
    
            if [context] =~ "^conn" {
                grok {
                   match => {"context" => "conn%{NUMBER:connect_id:int}"}
                }
            }
    
            if [message] =~ "ms$"  {
                 grok {
                   match => {"message" => "%{WORD:op_type}\s+.*}.*\}(\s+% 
    {NUMBER:spend_time:int}ms$)?"}
                }
            }
    
           if [message] =~ "^end\s+connection" {
                grok {
                   match => {"message" => "end\s+connection\s+% 
    {IPORHOST:client_ip}:%{NUMBER:client_port:int}.*"}
                   add_tag => ["end_connection"]
                }
            }
    
            if [message] =~ "^connection\s+accepted\s+from" {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    grok {
                   match => {"message" => 
    "connection\s+accepted\s+from\s+%{IPORHOST:client_ip}:% 
    {NUMBER:client_port:int}\s+#%{NUMBER:connect_id:int}.*"}                                                                                                                                        
    add_tag => ["start_connection"]
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    date {
                match => [ "timestamp", "UNIX", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
    "ISO8601"]
                remove_field => [ "timestamp" ]
            }
        }
    }
```